# Video is playing on top of the page instead of playing in the location where clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with positioning of the video opened when clicked. I have a image linked to youtube video. The image is abit down of the web page (we need to scroll a bit). When ever I click on the video the youtube link is opened at the top of the page instead of playing where clicked.Please suggest how to change the position of the video.
http://jsfiddle.net/UxLHR/21/

```
<div style="margin:-3px 20px 10px 14px;">
<a id="showYouTubeVideo" href="#" >

<img style="margin: -3px 20px 10px 14px;" src="" alt="Go"/>
</a>
</div>

<div id="ScanNCutoverlayBox"></div>
    <div id="ScanNCutdisplayBox">
        <div id="ScanNCutcloseX">X</div>
        <div id="ScanNCutdisplayBoxContentHolder">
            <iframe
                width="853"
                height="480"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM?autoplay=1"
                frameborder="0"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wiriting `e.preventDefault()` in `$("#showYouTubeVideo").click(function (e) {}`

EDIT:

preventDefault() stops from scrolling to top (at least on my browser...).

http://jsfiddle.net/UxLHR/22/

Also I don't like the way the modal is positioned, but it is another topic with a lot of different solutions.

Comment: Is there any mistake with css or js? O

Comment: If you click on 'GO', it should stay in the same position. Thus, scroll is be disabled. It works for me and should work for you. Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/UxLHR/22/ 

Postioning of the modal itself is messy because of both javascript and css. There are a lot of ways to do it. For example, you can set its CSS property `top` by calculating distance scrolled from top and adding a half of window height. Then you'll only need to use translate(x,y). Here's a hint for CSS: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: Actually I was using the same CSS file for the video1 already there for this page. Can you help me to correct the positioning of the modal?

Comment: the existing video uses the code from http://www.freestyle.mvla.net/webaudio/videoDisplay.php#

Comment: I am not sure I have enough time to dive deep into your css but I feel that you could get rid of JavaScript part which calculates center and simply make the modal fixed. Just like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/prb5haso/).

Don't put much effort into this task and better try to learn CSS well enough to be able to create such modals yourself.

As for now, my proposed solution with fixed modal should save a lots of time.

EDIT: highlighted link.